# BigQueryでテーブルの全カラム（フィールド）の欠損値を出力するsql文を書きたい

Tags: google-bigquery

BigQueryにて、あるテーブルの全フィールドの欠損値の合計数を出力するquery文を作成したいのですが、こちらは地道に全カラムごとにcountを取るしかないのでしょうか？

PythonのPandasであればシンプルなやり方があると思いますが、BigQuery内だけで完結してこのような表出力は可能かお教えいただけますと幸いです。

以下、元テーブルとクエリ結果のイメージ

＜元テーブル＞

| レコード番号 | col1 | col2 | col... | col100 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 | 100 | ... | 300 |
| 2 | 100 |  | ... | 100 |
| 3 |  | 300 | ... | 100 |

＜クエリ結果＞

⇒全フィールドで欠損値をカウント（※文字列空白は考慮しない）

| レコード番号 | col1 | col2 | col... | col100 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12314 | 71232 | ... | 12314 |